# By mistake, I called a Sinatra Ruby file app.py and it still worked, why?

Tags: ruby, rest, compiler-construction

I named a Ruby file app.py and it worked. I only noticed later. Why is that possible. It wasn't anything complicated, just a small Sinatra recipe but still, I don't understand.

Comment: How did you invoke it? If you said `ruby app.py` then it worked because you passed the filename to the Ruby interpreter, which tells it to interpret the file (it isn't concerned with what you named it, only that it is a valid Ruby file).

Comment: Yeah you're right. There's was no shebang either, only a Sinatra 'require' and a little function. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: That's the basics and I didn't get that.I didn't think about it.Why would I think the extension influences anything?

Comment: Because the only explanation for why you're confused by the outcome is that the file is named "app.py" instead of "app.rb". If that isn't it, then why did you think it wouldn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under Unix (say, Linux or similar), the first line of a script contains the path to its interpreter. The line's called Shebang or Crunchbang and looks like that:

```
#! /usr/bin/ruby
```

If you rename you file, the path to the interpreter still remains unchanged and therefore the script will be executed as before.

Comment: I guess it's the same thing since I invoke the file with the interpreter. Does that make sense?